# What is the configuration option devenv command switch meant for?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

What would be an example of how to build a C++ Visual Studio solution from the command line?

Comment: Which version of visual Studio are you talking about, VS6, 2003, 2005 or 2008?

Answer (score 0):

In  VS 2003, 2005 and 2008 - 
msbuild [solutionfile].sln

Comment: .vcproj file might need a few changes to use it with msbuild

Answer (score 0):

You coud also do something like this:
    **devenv.exe *SolutionName* /build**

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28VS.80%29.aspx) on MSDN for more info